# How to get the outerHTML after the first jquery method?

Tags: jquery

Anyone knows how to get the outerHTML from this point?....

```
  $("#sectionA tr[data-testlog='"+variableName+"']").first().outerHTML;
```

Returns an undefined....

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Answer (score 1):

`outerHTML` is a DOM property so you first would have to access the DOM element wrapped inside your jQuery object

You can do this using `each`

```
$(/*any jquery stuff*/).each(function(idx, domEl) {
    console.log(domEl.outerHTML);
});
```

If you know that you have exactly one match, or want to get only the first element, you should do:

```
$(SELECTOR)[0].outerHTML // or access any other **DOM** property
```

In your case:

```
$("#sectionA tr[data-testlog='"+variableName+"']")[0].outerHTML 
// first() would be redundant and unnecessary
```

Basically you can think of your jquery object as a wrapper around an array of DOM elements, that adds a gazillion functionalities that make developers happy, and functionality cross-browser compatible.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML) outerHTML is supported in:

```
Firefox (Gecko): 11    since 2012-03-13
Chrome: 0.2            since 2008-09-02
Internet Explorer 4.0  since 1997
Opera 7                since 2003-01-28
Safari 1.3             since 2006-01-12
```

Or as **akluth** suggested the other question you could

```
// select your element
$(SELECTOR)
// clone it (outside the dom of the page)
.clone()
// wrap it in another element
.wrap('<div>')
// get the parent - basically the wrapper you just added
.parent()
// and get its inner html - all the html your SELECTOR initially selected
.html();

// all in one line
$(SELECTOR).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
```

This would be a more costly operation done all by jQuery, but would as well be a crossbrowser solution. `outerHTML` might (or might not) be supported equally on all browsers/platforms.